# mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given PHP validation

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to validate a user login using PHP, however i get the following errors

> Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\db\sign_in_connect.php on line 18
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\db\sign_in_connect.php on line 22
>   Sorry, your credentials are not valid, Please try again.

this is my PHP code

```
<?php
try{
  $db = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root', '', 'car_rental') or die ("SQL is Off");

}
catch (Exception $e){
  echo "SQL is Off";
  exit;

}
echo "success"; 

$email = $_POST["email"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];



mysql_select_db("car_rental",$db);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT email, users FROM users WHERE email = $email");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($row["email"]==$email && $row["pass"]==$pass)
    echo"You are a validated user.";
else
    echo"Sorry, your credentials are not valid, Please try again.";


?>
```

Comment: Mixing `mysql and mysqli` in your code !! Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Comment: You are mixing `mysqli_` and `mysql_` functions. Use the newer `mysqli_` functions consequently (or `PDO`).

Comment: You must need to use only one method mysql or mysqli...

Comment: Stop using mysql as it is not safe. If you have some time, invest it in understanding PDO as a database connector. [One tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: well i'm learning php and mysql and am relatively new to this

Comment: One of the most weird piece of code I have ever seen in SO

Comment: is it maybe a possibility that you get this error because you define the database twice. outside the fact that you are mixing mysqli and mysql extensions

Comment: besides your mixing APIs, email is a string, treat it as one. Google "mysql string literals". Plus, we have no idea if your POST arrays have values. check for errors, you're not doing that.

Comment: you're also not selecting the `pass` column. Your code contains many errors and there are a few unknowns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with this .

```
   <?php
   try{
    $db = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root', '', 'car_rental') or die  ("SQL is Off");

     }
    catch (Exception $e){
   echo "SQL is Off";
    exit;

  }
 echo "success"; 

$email = $_POST["email"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];

mysqli_select_db($db,"car_rental");
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT email, users FROM users WHERE email =$email");

//$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 if($row["email"]==$email && $row["pass"]==$pass)
    echo"You are a validated user.";
   else
     echo"Sorry, your credentials are not valid, Please try again.";


    ?>
```

Comment: why define the database twice. He already defined the database in the connection string. Right here:  `$db = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root', '', 'car_rental')`

Comment: thanks, but i get this error now Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\db\sign_in_connect.php on line 20

Comment: you're making the same mistake with the email here.

Comment: Used this 
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);